# I always encountered various of errors when using Caffe to train a network using GPU

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

[image: some errors' screen capture]

[image: some errors' screen capture]

[image: some errors' screen capture]

[image: some errors' screen capture]

[image: some errors' screen capture]

My environment is GTX 1070 + Ubuntu 16.04.02 + CUDA 8.0 GA2 + Caffe 1.0.

And using the NVIDIA driver which is in the CUDA .run setup file.

And the network I trained are ResNet-50 and ResNet-101. But I have encountered with this problem on training other models, like Faster R-CNN.

Can anyone help me?

Is my card broken?

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you run all tests after building caffe? have all the tests passed?

Comment: I haven't...let me have a try.

Comment: [----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2041 tests from 267 test cases ran. (249671 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2041 tests.

Comment: try rebooting your machine

Comment: I have rebooted, no use...